# prog-mode-map Keybinding

Tags: key-bindings

I'm trying to add a keybinding to prog-mode-map, which is supposed to be valid in all programming maps, but I can't be doing it right, cause I have to add lines, like the second one, to have it working in each map

```
(define-key prog-mode-map (kbd "C-M-w r") 'eglot-rename)

(define-key c++-mode-map (kbd "C-M-w r") 'eglot-rename)
```

Any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong?;)

Answer (score 2):

You have to make `C-M-w` a [prefix key](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Keys.html) first (by default it it bound to `append-next-kill`):

```el
(setq c-m-w-keymap (make-sparse-keymap))
(define-key prog-mode-map (kbd "C-M-w") c-m-w-keymap)
```

*Then* you can add keybindings to it:

```el
(define-key c-m-w-keymap (kbd "r") #'eglot-rename)
```

Then both `prog-mode` and its children (e.g. `c++-mode`) will know about it.

EDIT: ... and since the above hijacks an existing keybinding in order to allow the key to become a prefix key, you might want to add a binding in the new keymap to replace the old binding, e.g.:

```el
(define-key c-m-w-keymap (kbd "a") #'append-next-kill)
```

Alternatively, as @phils suggests in a comment, you might choose an unused key, e.g. `C-M-z` is not used in `prog-mode-keymap`.

I tend to avoid such ad-hoc bindings, primarily because if I don't use them often enough I forget about their existence; instead I tend to define function keys[1]  as prefix keys for clusters of related commands. I can remember only a few of those too, but I can add stickers on the rest to remind me for which cluster a particular function key is a prefix, and I can use something like `<f5> C-h` to find what's hidden behind the `<f5>` prefix key.

---

[1] You might want to only use `<f5>`-`<f12>` - Emacs defines the first four by default.

Comment: For the same reason, consider using some other prefix which doesn't conflict.

Comment: actually, it worked if I inserted ampersand, cause I already have defined it as a prefix-key, (define-key prog-mode-map (kbd "C-M-w r") #'eglot-rename)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean: where did you insert ampersand?

Comment: Sorry, I mean to say hash sign.

Comment: You mean `#'eglot-rename` instead of `'eglot-rename`? If so, that only tells the compiler that it is dealing with a function, so that it can warn you if the function is not defined. See the `function` special form (for which `#'` is a shorthand, similar to using `'` for the `quote` special from) in [Anonymous Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Anonymous-Functions.html). When applied to a symbol, `#'` does nothing more than what is described above: in particular, it is functionally equivalent to a plain `'` in that case.